# mongodb query with array

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have this collection:

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5728cd81c08460ead'), "age"=>4, "name"=>"Diogo"}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5728cd81c08460ead'), "age"=>22, "name"=>"Tiago"}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5728cd81c08460ead'), "age"=>15, "name"=>"Marie"}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5728cd81c08460ead'), "age"=>2, "name"=>"JJ"}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5728cd81c08460ead'), "age"=>44, "name"=>"John"}
```

and this array of names:

```
names_array = ["John", "Marie", "Tiago"]
```

How can I use names_array to search for names in mongodb collection?

I want this output:

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5728cd81c08460ead'), "age"=>4, "name"=>"Diogo"}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5728cd81c08460ead'), "age"=>22, "name"=>"Tiago"}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5728cd81c08460ead'), "age"=>15, "name"=>"Marie"}
```

this query not work :

```
coll.find( { name: names_array } )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coll.find('name' => { '$in' => names_array } } )
```

Comment: I can't. undefined method `where' for #<Mongo::Collection:0x007fb2f912a738>

Comment: `where` method available in the mongo `ORM`.